# Is the middle power option 50% or 60%?

Tags: interaction-design, controls, physical, industrial-design

A friend of mine has a blender with 6 control selections: One off position, and five power settings in order of less to more power. Example below:

[image: 6 control options]

A discussion has erupted over whether or not the middle power option (3) **ought** to represent:

A) 50% power (The middle is surely 50%):

[image]

B) 60% power (There are 6 positions if 0% is included, there is no middle position as such, and so assuming a linear scale):

[image]

While this isn't exactly a life and death situation, I would be interested in seeking more opinions. We are roughly split 50/50 on **what it ought to be** (yes, we could verify what it **is** by dismantling the blender and examining the circuity, but no one is interested in that minor detail) :)

Comment: Who says that power increase is uniformly distributed over all the settings?

Comment: Could you add a picture of what the dial looks like? Is the 3 in the middle or ofset to one side?

Comment: I'm afraid no picture is available, but I'm told the 3 is physically in the middle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The percentage doesn't matter, what matters is what you do with each of the speed levels.**

Was a person with proper knowledge of the tool (and its use cases) involved in discerning this enigma? Most of the times, these things have levels to please cooks and kitchen-passionate individuals who would know exactly what kind of outcome is achieved with every speed level of the blender; whether it's a chunky Salsa, or a Smoothie (as you can tell, for me blenders should have only an on/off button)

The right answer to your question is not going to be given by an engineer, or a casual user of the blender, but by a cook! :)

Comment: +1 for bringing the perspective of the actual user into this!

Answer (score 3):

This certainly depends on the blender but your first option *seems* wrong. The jumps in speed are not uniform. You get a huge boost from 3 to 4 and almost no difference from 4 to 5. Without dismantling the blender, I'd say you should be able to simply *hear* that that this is not the case!

What I expect is that the speed of the blade increments uniformly between power levels. So, each stop should follow on a quadratic curve in terms of power which would translate in a linear increase in rotational speed.

So, from a user-experience point-of-view, I would expect it to follow neither of your examples.

Answer (score 3):

In engineering terms, if it is linear it is 60%.  If not, then nobody here knows.

If it started at 1 and not 0, then it would be 50%.

Comment: Who says that power increase is uniformly distributed over all the settings? I added this comment to the question as well. It is an assumption that seems to have no ground?

Comment: @MarjanVenema I said "if it is linear".  If it's not, then there is no way of saying what it should be.

Comment: Ah, missed those 4 words... Sorry

Comment: Good answer. The key phrase is 'If not, then nobody here knows.' For example, another possibility is a starting point of greater than 20% followed by a linear progression - this is based on the assumption that the blender at very low power is not capable of blending anything that people normally put in a blender.

Answer (score 0):

From a user experience perspective, the key is to have a 'middle setting'. It doesn't really matter WHAT it is, specifically, but if your users like the idea of 'medium' then just make sure there is a medium setting...be it a number, letter or just a tick mark in the center.